# Other words for "spent money"

Tags: word-request

What's another word for "spent money/money spent (as of now)?"

Are there other words you know aside from "expenditure" or "expenses." Something that would imply what has been spent as of now?

Comment: Could you provide an example sentence where you would use this word?

Comment: Maybe [**outlay**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/outlay).  But like cigien says, you really need to give us an example of where you want to use this word.  *Outlay* might be fine in a business or government context, but it would sound weird if you were talking to your friend about your *outlay* on candy.

Comment: @stangdon I think outlay is okay. thank you for answering my question and not being mean.